# Simple GraphQL Query using the Graph

Tags: graphql

So I'm trying to learn graphql I've been playing around with the [ENS subgraph on the graph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/ensdomains/ens?selected=playground)

For now I'm just trying to do some simple filtering:  I would like to be able to filter by the property name:

```
{
  domains(name:"cocacola.eth") {
    id
    name
    labelName
    labelhash
  }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I was looking at an old version of graphql when I tried making that query but when following another online I found I can specify using the where parameter:

```
{
  domains(where:{name: "cocacola.eth"}) {
    id
    name
    labelName
    labelhash
  }
}
```